# Flow and Scroll Text around non rectangular shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, word-wrap

I have created a little code which lets text flow around some shapes. Using a simple Javsscript:
See http://jsfiddle.net/lobin/YPBmJ/2/

What I try to achieve is that the shape is fixed and when scrolling, the text will scroll around the shape. I let the shape stay fixed via a JS bound to the scroll event, but it seams the rendering does not adopt itself to the new situation (See jsfiddle).

Any Ideas how that could work?

HTML:

```
<div class="box"><div class="shapewrapper"></div>Some long Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.box .shapewrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.box .shapewrapper .left {
    background-color: #f00;
    height:1px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

JS:

```
    var hbratio=10;
    var h=$(".box").height();
    for (i=h;i>0;i--) {
        b=Math.round(i/10);
        $(".shapewrapper").prepend('<div class="left" style="width:'+b+'px;" />');
    }
    $(".box").scroll(function() {
        var y=$(".box").scrollTop();
        $(".shapewrapper").css("top",eval(y)+'px');
    });
```

(Idea from http://www.csstextwrap.com)

Comment: sorry, comment on wrong place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to achieve this with css (alone), but I came up with a solution that involves jQuery.

Whenever the user scrolls the ".box" element, the top margin of the first ".left" element should be adjusted.

```
  $(".box").scroll(function() {
        $(".box .left").first().css("margin-top", $(this).scrollTop()+"px");
    });
```

In order to make this work, the user must actually scroll the box element, so I changed the CSS of the box to overflow:auto. It would also work of the user scrolls the parent-element, but then the selector for the scroll event would need to be changed to the parent element.

I created a new **jsFiddle** to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/EwQ5J/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Preli, I tried to make a wrapper around the shapes. It works like it should!

Comment: I am glad it worked.Please set my answer to "accepted answer" if it helped you.